# Linux/Unix using awk function with logical &&

Tags: linux, unix, awk, logical-operators

```
ls -la | awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s\t%s\n","Name","Size"}{if ($9 == "." && $5 == 0) print $9,"\t"$5}'

drwxrws---+ 6 rsy512 group20 4096 Oct 24 20:54 .
drwxrws---+ 6 root   group20   68 Oct 24 14:19 ..
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20  568 Mar  3  2010 adhoc
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost1.c
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost2
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost3.cpp 
drwxr-s---+ 2 rsy512 group20    6 Mar  3  2010 .ghostdir
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20   21 Feb 17  2010 input4.txt
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20 1878 Feb 26  2008 lab1.cpp
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20 1171 Feb  4  2010 Lab2.cpp
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20 1013 Mar  3  2010 proc
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20  109 Mar  3  2010 prog1.c
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20  104 Mar  3  2010 prog2.c
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 prog3.c.txt
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 prog.4c 
drwxrws---+ 2 rsy512 group20    6 Mar  3  2010 programs.c 
drwxrws---+ 2 rsy512 group20    6 Mar  3  2010 programs.cpp
-rw-rw----. 1 rsy512 group20   46 Oct 24 20:54 script1_t20 
drwxrws---+ 2 rsy512 group20    6 Mar  3  2010 test1
```

I need to output the 3 files ".ghost..." and their file size. With the header name and size.

Im trying to use a logical AND (&&) to achieve this effect. Only after both conditions are satisfied, proceed to print
the information. Add a header ,"Name", "Size" to your results. Add this awk script (preceded
by ls -l |) to the content of script1_tXX

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts/code, keep it up. IMHO experts never advice to parse ls output to any parsing tool. Kindly elaborate more on what you are actually trying to achieve here, thank you.

Comment: A minor tweak to your awk command should give you your expected outcome on your example data (`ls -la | awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s\t%s\n","Name","Size"}{if ($9 ~ /^\./ && $5 == 0) print $9 "\t" $5}'`) but it would probably be better to use the `find` command, e.g. @karakfa's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your's `ls -la` output be

```
drwxrws---+ 6 rsy512 group20 4096 Oct 24 20:54 .
drwxrws---+ 6 root   group20   68 Oct 24 14:19 ..
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20  568 Mar  3  2010 adhoc
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost1.c
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost2
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost3.cpp 
drwxr-s---+ 2 rsy512 group20    6 Mar  3  2010 .ghostdir
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20   21 Feb 17  2010 input4.txt
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20 1878 Feb 26  2008 lab1.cpp
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20 1171 Feb  4  2010 Lab2.cpp
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20 1013 Mar  3  2010 proc
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20  109 Mar  3  2010 prog1.c
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20  104 Mar  3  2010 prog2.c
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 prog3.c.txt
-rwxrw----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 prog.4c 
drwxrws---+ 2 rsy512 group20    6 Mar  3  2010 programs.c 
drwxrws---+ 2 rsy512 group20    6 Mar  3  2010 programs.cpp
-rw-rw----. 1 rsy512 group20   46 Oct 24 20:54 script1_t20 
drwxrws---+ 2 rsy512 group20    6 Mar  3  2010 test1
```

then

```
$9 == "."
```

does check if whole 9th field is just dot, this condition only holds for one line in your's `ls -la` output namely

```
drwxrws---+ 6 rsy512 group20 4096 Oct 24 20:54 .
```

but you want to

> output the 3 files ".ghost..."

so you should be looking for `.ghost` somewhere inside 9th field, this for example might be expressed as

```
$9 ~ /\.ghost/
```

note that `.` needs to be escaped to mean literal dot, above condition holds for lines

```
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost1.c
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost2
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost3.cpp 
drwxr-s---+ 2 rsy512 group20    6 Mar  3  2010 .ghostdir
```

if you wish to exclude dirs you might do that by adding condition

```
!/^d/
```

which might be read as line does not (`!`) starts with (`^`) character `d`, therefore complete condition might be written as

```
!/^d/ && $9 ~ /\.ghost/ && $5 == 0
```

which does hold for

```
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost1.c
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost2
-rw-r-----. 1 rsy512 group20    0 Mar  3  2010 .ghost3.cpp
```

**Disclaimer**: this assumes you never uses any whitespace in files names.

*(test in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

you can do the required filtering with `find`, not sure printing the 0 size will do but here it is.

```
$  { echo -e "name\tsize"; find . -type f -name ".*" -size 0 -printf "%p\t%k KB\n"; } | 
     column -ts$'\t'
```